# Сделать запрос post из расширения firefox на сервер php

Tags: javascript, php, post, firefox

Нужен пример как отправить запрос с расширения firfox в php на сайте.
Есть страничка с php которая с формы меняет строку в файле.

```
<?php
    # Если кнопка нажата
    if( isset( $_POST['nazvanie_knopki'] ) )
    {
        $line=3; // номер строки, которую нужно изменить

$replace = $_POST["user"]; // на что нужно изменить
$filename = 'play.txt'; // имя файла 

$file = file($filename);
$file[$line-1] = $replace.PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents($filename, join('', $file));


        echo 'Ссылка сохранена!';
    }
?>
```

как сделать простенькое расширение которое будет отправлять некий запрос в этот php на сервере???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен что правильно понял твой вопрос, надеюсь правильно.

```
         $parameters = array(
         'Params' => '1',
         'Params2' => $test,
         'Params3' => '2',
        );

        $query = file_get_contents('https://mysite.ru/file?' . http_build_query($parameters));
        $request = json_decode($query, true);
```

Comment: нужно код для РАСШИРЕНИЯ firefox, который будет отправлять запрос на php страницу которая обработает этот запрос обработает. ваш пример не обрабатывается.

Comment: Всё таки получилось?